# Laravel: BadMethodCallException error trying to add post to database

Tags: php, html, laravel

On my website, a registered user can create a post. The post includes the title, type, subtype, cover_image, and body. Recently I included title, type, and subtype, which is what created the error. It was working fine before I included these columns. When clicking the create post button it presents me with the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRquired does not exist.
```

Not sure why it gives this error my validation seems fine.

Here is my view:

```
<section class="row new-post">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <header><h3>What do you have to say</h3></header>
        <form action="{{ route('postcreate') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="type">Type</label>
                <select name="type" class="form-control">
                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subtype">Subtype</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subtype">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cover_image">Upload Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="cover_image" class="form-control" id="cover_image">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="body" rows="5" placeholder="your post"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create post</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is my postController.php method:

```
public function postCreatePost(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'rquired',
        'type' => 'required',
        'subtype' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'cover_image' => 'required|image||nullable|max:1999'
    ]);



        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension; 
        $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);


    $post = new Post(); 
    $post->title = $request['title'];
    $post->type = $request['type'];
    $post->subtype = $request['subtype'];
    $post->body = $request['body'];
    $post->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
    $message = 'There was an error';
    if($request->user()->posts($post)->save($post)){; //points here
        $message = 'post successfully created';
    }
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => $message]);
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code: `'title' => 'rquired',`. This line should say: `'title' => 'required',`.

Comment: You should make that an answer, @Dominik.

Comment: oh, my bad that was a silly mistake, not sure how I didn't spot that. @Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRquired does not exist.

The exception from above says it all - you have a spelling mistake in your code. The line:

```
'title' => 'rquired',
```

should say:

```
'title' => 'required',
```